# How to determine App download date?

Tags: iphone, app-store

How do I determine the date(s) an app I developed was downloaded from the App Store?

Comment: If you want to access this from Object-C, say so... otherwise I think this should be on superuser.com. Voting to close.

Comment: Do you want to know the date(s) an app you developed was downloaded from the App Store?

Comment: gerry3: Yes, that is my requirement .

Comment: Doug Neiner: yes, from objective c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if it violates the SDK agreement, but you can check your `iTunesMetadata.plist`, which contains a `purchaseDate` key as an `NSDate`.

Comment: How to find out iTunesMetadata.plist?

Comment: `[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iTunesMetadata.plist"]`

Comment: shall i need to add that file ? i am not getting any thing.
id data = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iTunesMetadata.plist"];
 
 NSLog(@"data ::: %@",[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:data error:nil]);
 NSLog(@"att :: %@",[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:data error:nil]);

This code give me null.
Can u give some detail about this .
thanks

Comment: This file won't exist until the customer download it from AppStore.